# Can i know how to solve the error for below code in python

Tags: python

Can i know how to solve the error for below code in python

```
text = input("Enter your text here :")
if text.find("make a lot of money" !=-1 or "Make a lot of money"!=-1 or "MAKE A LOT OF MONEY"!=-1):
    print("This Text contains spam words ")
```

ERROR:

`Enter your text here :MAKE A LOT OF MONEY`

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "e:\Python Course with Notes\Practice set\Chapter 6\Chap_6_pr_3.py", line 2, in <module>
    if text.find("make a lot of money" !=-1 or "Make a lot of money"!=-1 or 
"MAKE A LOT OF MONEY" !=-1):
TypeError: must be str, not bool
```

Comment: Try formatting your code so that it is easier to read using back ticks (`)

Comment: Just so you know, using `str.find` just to know if a string contains a substring is not necessary. To make it much simpler, and avoid those `or`s, you should just do: `if "make a lot of money" in text.lower():`

Answer (score 1):

your formatting of the find function is wrong, you need to evaluate the result of the function like this

```
text = input("Enter your text here :")
if (text.find("make a lot of money") !=-1) or (text.find("Make a lot of money") !=-1) or (text.find("MAKE A LOT OF MONEY"!=-1):
    print("This Text contains spam words ")
```

Comment: it worked . Done